# JAVA: MVC with GUI and Console input?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, console-application

I am working on a project(a game) where there is a GUI to play the game. Now, I am asked to implement a console mode as well for the project. So basically, a user playing game with GUI can in between type commands on the console as well to take actions.

I am using MVC architecture for the game. But now since I have to implement taking input from commands as well, I am not sure how to integrate such a feature with GUI? So, basically I want to perform actions based on input from the console as well as input from GUI?

[image]

Something like above, where I can add player using GUI as well as console.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they running in the JVM process or separately?

Comment: They are running in the same program, not separately, in the JVM process.

Comment: So part of the MVC is the concept of the observer pattern.  You CLI and your GUI should be sharing the same model(s), a change made by either to the model(s) should generate a event of some kind, through which your view(s)/controller(s) are notified and can take appropriate action.  Swing calls these "listeners"